# how to remove a method with a callback or otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that animates an object with a delay of 800 ms:

```
$('#navMenu').mousemove(function (e) {
        thisX = e.pageX

        if (thisX >= 1625) {
            $('#prbBtnHolder').animate({ left: '-=150' }, 300).delay(800);
        }
});
```

If the `#prbBtnHolder` has a certain `css left` property i want to be able to remove the `delay()`method and stop the animation. How do i do this? This is what I've tried so far:

```
//...
$('#prbBtnHolder').animate({ left: '-=150' }, 300).delay(800);
if ($('#prbBtnHolder').css('left') < -100) {
     $(this).animate({left: '-=0px'});
}
```

But this does not remove the `delay` method nor does it achieve the desired effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try using jQuery.fx.off to stop te animation, maybe this works to the delay method too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clear the effects queue, you'll need to use the step callback to see if your condition is met.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('#prbBtnHolder').animate({
  left: '-=150'
},    
{
  duration: 300,
  step: function(now, fx) {
    if (now < -100) {
      // uncomment and you'll see the next animation
      $(fx.elem).clearQueue().stop();            
    }
  }
}).delay(800).animate({ width: '200px', height: '200px' }, 300);
```

Here is a jsbin example:

http://jsbin.com/utejew/3

Answer (score 0):

**`$(this).clearQueue();`**
[jQuery Docs for clearQueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

Removes all elements in the effect Queue for the given Element. Otherwise you could use js native `setTimeout`function to animate which can easily be cleared with `clearTimeout`.

Before you Animate `$('#prbBtnHolder')` you can calculate how far the Button is away from `-100` and animate it only that far.